# How to fetch data from two different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to fetch the records from two different tables in the same database. But I encounter an error.

Query:

```
use AdventureWorks2014

select 
    cast(departmentID as nvarchar), ModifiedDate 
from 
    [HumanResources].[Department]
union
select 
    LoginID, JobTitle 
from 
    [HumanResources].[Employee]
```

Error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks All

Comment: Columns returned by the `union`ed queries must have the same datatype. The first subquery returns a date in column 2, while the secondsub query returns a string. Hence the error.

Comment: Could you please provide the schema for tables?

Comment: In your first query, you (likely) have a date column `ModifiedDate` which you are trying to perform a `union` command with (likely) a varchar `JobTitle` column. The columns in order should be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, but I am thinking that you are likely trying to get the records from the `[HumanResources].[Employee]` table and their corresponding department via the `[HumanResources].[Department]` table.

If this is the case, then I am assuming that there would be a key relationship between the tables. For example, your `Employee` table could have a `DepartmentId` column for which you can then perform a join.

**Employee Table**

```
LoginId
FirstName
LastName
JobTitle
DepartmentId
```

**Department Table**

```
DepartmentId
DepartmentName
ModifiedDate
```

Then for a table structure like above, you just need to make a `JOIN` operation on the table.

```
SELECT emp.LoginId, emp.FirstName, emp.LastName, dep.DepartmentName
FROM Employee emp
INNER JOIN Department dep ON dep.DepartmentId = emp.DepartmentId
```

If you can post your table structure and the desired data output, then I am pretty sure we could help you formulate the query better.

Answer (score 0):

You used `UNION`, so the datatypes of the columns in both select statements should be the same.
And you are fetching the data from the `Department` and `Employee` table. Here, you have to use the join between `Department` and `EmployeeDepartmentHistory` on `DepartmentID` and join between `EmployeeDepartmentHistory` and `Employee` table on `BusinessEntityID` to get the columns you have posted.

```
SELECT 
D.DepartmentID
,D.ModifiedDate
,E.LoginID
,E.JobTitle
FROM [HumanResources].[Department] D
INNER JOIN [HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory] EDH
ON D.DepartmentID = EDH.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN [HumanResources].[Employee] E
ON EDH.BusinessEntityID = E.BusinessEntityID
```

Here is the sample:

[image]